# How to get the Summary to show centered instead of left aligned (only the title)

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to know how to center the title of the contents table, but just the word **Summary**.

Here are my packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=15mm,left=15mm}
```

[image]

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Is tocloft a new package I need to include?

Comment: If you want to customize your ToC easily, then yes. Otherwise, you will most certainly need to use primitive TeX syntax every time you want to customize something

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Your solution didn't work

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh Your modification still doesn't work :(

Comment: If it still does not work, then you must show more of your source code. Otherwise, even others may not be able to help further.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh I've posted all my packages above. The rest shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh It has worked, I noticed I was doing something wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You did not provide an MWE, but here is something that could solve it. The title of table of contents is stored in `\contentsname`. Hence, you can use `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hspace{\fill} Summary \hspace*{\fill}}` to center it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{top=15mm,left=15mm}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\toctitlefont}{\LARGE \bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\centering \toctitlefont}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hspace{\fill} Summary \hspace*{\fill}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

**Related:** use `tocloft` package if you want to do detailed customization of your ToC.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: The code above should work now. I just forgot to place `*` after `\hspace`